# Is my order complete return approach correct?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When a customer is returned to the following URL (example);

```
http://prestashop.dev/index.php?action=completed&controller=callback&fc=module&hmac={valid-hmac}&merchant_order_id=14&module=chippin
```

After a successful payment, It will call on this FrontController sub-class;

```
class ChippinCallbackModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function postProcess()
    {
        $chippin = new Chippin();

        $payment_response = new PaymentResponse();
        $payment_response->getPostData();

        // if a valid response from gateway
        if(ChippinValidator::isValidHmac($payment_response)) {

            // "action" is passed as a param in the URL. don't worry, the Hmac can tell if it's valid or not.
            if ($payment_response->getAction() === "completed") {

                // payment_response->getMerchantOrderId() will just return the id_order from the orders table
                $order_id = Order::getOrderByCartId((int) ($payment_response->getMerchantOrderId()));
                $order = new Order($order_id);
                // this will update the order status for the benefit of the merchant.
                $order->setCurrentState(Configuration::get('CP_OS_PAYMENT_COMPLETED'));

                // assign variables to smarty (copied this from another gateway, don't really understand smarty)
                $this->context->smarty->assign(
                    array(
                        'order' => $order->reference,
                    )
                );

                // display this template
                $this->setTemplate('confirmation.tpl');
```

I'm quite new to Prestashop. I'm just not sure if this is technically done or not. The `confirmation.tlp` view does display with the `order->reference` and the order status is updated to "Completed" but is this all I need?

Are there any other considerations? I have the opportunity to call a hookDisplayPaymentReturn at this point but why should I?

I seem to have a pretty standard return page. Is this enough;

[image]

Update - Do I just call a hook something like;

```
public function displayPaymentReturn()
{

    $params = $this->displayHook();

    if ($params && is_array($params)) {
        return Hook::exec('displayPaymentReturn', $params, (int) $this->module->id);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see everything seems okay for me.

You should consider adding `hookDisplayPaymentReturn` it allows other modules to add code to your confirmation page. For example a Google module could add javascript code that sends order informations to analytics on confirmation page.

---

**EDIT**

```php
class ChippinCallbackModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function postProcess()
    {
        $chippin = new Chippin();

        $payment_response = new PaymentResponse();
        $payment_response->getPostData();

        // if a valid response from gateway
        if(ChippinValidator::isValidHmac($payment_response)) {

            // "action" is passed as a param in the URL. don't worry, the Hmac can tell if it's valid or not.
            if ($payment_response->getAction() === "completed") {

                // payment_response->getMerchantOrderId() will just return the id_order from the orders table
                $order_id = Order::getOrderByCartId((int) ($payment_response->getMerchantOrderId()));
                $order = new Order($order_id);
                // this will update the order status for the benefit of the merchant.
                $order->setCurrentState(Configuration::get('CP_OS_PAYMENT_COMPLETED'));

                // assign variables to smarty (copied this from another gateway, don't really understand smarty)
                $this->context->smarty->assign(
                    array(
                        'order' => $order->reference,
                        'hookDisplayPaymentReturn' => Hook::exec('displayPaymentReturn', $params, (int) $this->module->id);
                    )
                );

                $cart = $this->context->cart;
                $customer = new Customer($cart->id_customer);

                Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart='.$cart->id.'&id_module='.$this->module->id.'&id_order='.$order->id.'&key='.$customer->secure_key);
```

And in your module :

```php
class myPaymentModule extends PaymentModule
{
    public function install()
    {
        if (!parent::install() || !$this->registerHook('paymentReturn'))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    // Example taken from bankwire module
    public function hookPaymentReturn($params)
    {
        $state = $params['objOrder']->getCurrentState();

        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'total_to_pay' => Tools::displayPrice($params['total_to_pay'], $params['currencyObj'], false),
            'bankwireDetails' => Tools::nl2br($this->details),
            'bankwireAddress' => Tools::nl2br($this->address),
            'bankwireOwner' => $this->owner,
            'status' => 'ok',
            'id_order' => $params['objOrder']->id
        ));
        if (isset($params['objOrder']->reference) && !empty($params['objOrder']->reference))
            $this->smarty->assign('reference', $params['objOrder']->reference);
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'confirmation.tpl');
    }
}
```

Comment: what so instead of calling the `confirmation.tpl` page directly, I should do it in the hook? Or just have an empty hook method? - see my update

Comment: You're using a shortcut for displaying confirmation template. In reality you should redirect to the order-confirmation controller which will do the process for you. And in your module you can hook on `displayPaymentReturn` or `displayOrderConfirmation`. See my edit

Comment: Have a look at `bankwire` module (it's a default Prestashop module). It's a really simple module to understand.

Comment: I've seen that `controller=order-confirmation` before and, yes, I have noticed I have bypassed the OrderConfirmationController. I can work with the bankwire. Does it matter if I can't call `$cart = $this->context->cart`? I can just create a new Cart like I'm already doing?

Comment: Yes as long as the cart exist there's no problem.